# Passing JSON String to Google Charts in Play Framework controller to Scala view is not recognized nor do the charts display

Tags: scala, playframework, google-visualization

I have a controller in Play that passes a string in JSON format to a Scala view:

```
public Result reportsPieChart() {
        String jsonString = "{cols: [{id: 'task', label: 'Task', type: 'string'}, {id: 'hours', label: 'Hours per Day', type: 'number'}],rows: [{c:[{v: 'Work'}, {v: 11}]}, {c:[{v: 'Eat'}, {v: 2}]}, {c:[{v: 'Commute'}, {v: 2}]}, {c:[{v: 'Watch TV'}, {v:2}]}, {c:[{v: 'Sleep'}, {v:7, f:'7.000'}]}]}";              
        return ok(piechart.render(jsonString));
}
```

In the view, I am using this variable in the Javascript to display the Google Chart:

```
@(jsonString: String)

@main(null) {
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
            google.charts.load('current', {
                packages : [ 'corechart' ]
            });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

            function drawChart() {
                var jsonString = "@jsonString";
                var newJSON = jsonString.replace(/&#x27;/g, "'");
                console.log("newJSON: " + newJSON);

                // Define the chart to be drawn.
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(newJSON);

                // Instantiate and draw the chart.
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('myPieChart'));
                chart.draw(data, null);
            }
        </script>
    <section id="displayResults" style="padding: 30px;">
         <!-- Identify where the chart should be drawn. -->
        <div id="myPieChart"/>          
    </section>
}
```

WHen passing the newJSON variable to the DataTable, it seems not to recognize it -- no errors, nothing to the console -- and does not display any charts.

The newJSON variable prints out to console in the correct format:

```
newJSON: {cols: [{id: 'task', label: 'Task', type: 'string'}, {id: 'hours', label: 'Hours per Day', type: 'number'}],rows: [{c:[{v: 'Work'}, {v: 11}]}, {c:[{v: 'Eat'}, {v: 2}]}, {c:[{v: 'Commute'}, {v: 2}]}, {c:[{v: 'Watch TV'}, {v:2}]}, {c:[{v: 'Sleep'}, {v:7, f:'7.000'}]}]}
```

I am following the instructions from Google:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#datatable-class

In the example, I copied that JSON into my string.

Is there something I missing within Scala in a view to get this variable to work?  According to Google, you can pass a literal string to the DataTable.

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a little trial and error, the solution is to wrap both name and values in double quotes.

My JSON String looks like this:

```
String jsonString = "{'cols': [{'id': 'task', 'label': 'Task', 'type': 'string'}, {'id': 'hours', 'label': 'Hours per Day', 'type': 'number'}],'rows': [{'c':[{'v': 'Work'}, {'v': 11}]}, {'c':[{'v': 'Eat'}, {'v': 2}]}, {'c':[{'v': 'Commute'}, {'v': 2}]}, {'c':[{'v': 'Watch TV'}, {'v':2}]}, {'c':[{'v': 'Sleep'}, {'v':7, 'f':'7.000'}]}]}";
```

and I changed the Javascript to:

```
var newJSON = jsonString.replace(/&#x27;/g, '"');
```

Works like a charm...